Putting Image as a child in ListView causes the software to crash
I'm developing a manga software using .net maui, my main platform is Android. Here is my code.
            <ListView
                x:Name="listView"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUrls}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding}" />
                                <Label
                                    FontFamily=""
                                    HeightRequest="600"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading, Source={x:Reference img}}"
                                    Text="loding..."
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

Here is the problem when loading images. When the loaded images are too large, they will throw Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Canvas: trying to draw too large(109224768bytes) bitmap.' and crash. This was fixed with app hardwareAcceleration turned off or turn off to adapt to different screen densities, but it reduced the smoothness of swiping, which seems to be a bit of a cost-off, and I wonder if there is a better way.
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:largeHeap="true" ... />
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false" />
(Just now I found that the problem has nothing to do with Image control. Rather, it is generated under the dual influence of a specific image and a scrollable view (e.g. ScrollView, ListView, CollectionView). For example, this image https://s1.baozicdn.com/scomic/woduzishengji-duburedicestudio/0/1-7ymq/24.jpg have a problem
And other pictures such as https://s1.baozicdn.com/scomic/woduzishengji-duburedicestudio/0/1-7ymq/25.jpg are no problem，If you add Margin="0,0,0,200" to the Image, or if the Image is not placed in the ListView, but in the StackLayout, the exception will not appear)
I would appreciate it if anyone would be willing to help
I looked up a lot of information but didn't find a good solution

Please read [ask] before posting.  You’ll get better responses if you edit your question to focus on one specific problem instead of multiple ones.  And it would be helpful to know exactly how large these images are

As Jason suggested, please help elaborate more specific on how large the images are. Also, please help create Minimal, Reproducible Example and add it to your post.

These pictures come from the Internet, they are of different sizes, I don't know their specific size, maybe it can be seen from the exception thrown（109224768bytes） bitmap., I'm just a rookie, I don't know if it's feasible

@chene Please try to add the android:anyDensity property to the manifest, referene link

Thankfully, this does fix the crash but it also causes some other problems, as with turning off hardware acceleration, I'll see if there's a better way to do it. Thank you very much.

@chene No worries, I'll post it as an answer as it'll help others facing the same issue!

Ok, thanks for your idea of this issue

At present, I use FFImageLoading.MAUI to solve this problem. I don't need to turn off hardware acceleration or turn off image density, which makes the picture scroll without the effect of stuck.
It also provides loading placeholders and error placeholders, which by the way solves another problem for me: using label and image's isloading attribute as a placeholder in loading and the label sometimes disappears when the picture is not displayed.
I think it's very good to use it these days, I hope it will help people who encounter the same problem.

You can try to add the android:anyDensity property to the file AndroidManifest.xml like below:
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="false" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" />
</manifest>

Reference link
